# How to statically link a Swift framework to a Swift framework?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, clang, static-linking

I have 2 frameworks, which are both Swift Statically-linked frameworks.

This means that my `Mach-O Type` is `Static Library` for both of the targets.

One of the targets (`A`) depends on another target (`B`).

I successfully archive `A`, and then I successfully archive `B`, linking against `A`. Embedding is enabled, however I don't seem to find any mentions of A in the exported build artifacts.

However, when I import archived and exported `B` in another target, it gives me a compilation error:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'A'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A.someMethodInsideA() -> Swift.Int", referenced from:
  B.someMethodInsideB() -> Swift.Int in B(B.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

You see, I set the A's Mach-O Type to `Static Library`, so I expect A's binaries to be completely embedded into B with static linkage, but this doesn't happen for some reason.

How can I embed a static framework inside a static framework?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try setting the following flags in xcode:

`-Xlinker -undefined -Xlinker dynamic_lookup`

Regards.